Mission Control requires me to click the app in order to start moving it
After resetting my system for unrelated reasons, I seem to notice the change in Mission Control behavior when using touchpad.
I used to bring it with 3 finger up gesture and then double tap the window to start moving it to another desktop if needed. Now the attempt to double tap the window is interrupted by making the window active and in order to move the window I need to click it with the touchpad to start moving.
UPD:
This behavior also transitions to taking a screenshot of an area, I need to click the screen in order to start creating or adjusting the area of the screenshot. Same goes for tapping twice on text to start selecting it, I need to click the trackpad twice in order to start selecting text.
Connected bluetooth mouse works just fine, clicking on the window allows me to move it.
M1 MBA, Mac OS 14.6.1

Needed to turn on "Use Trackpad for dragging"
Go to Settings > Accessibility > Pointer Control > Trackpad Options > Use Trackpad for Dragging
I hate how obscure some of the settings might be sometimes..
